# Cambiar el color de un dia en control Calendar de Winforms

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Agradecería me dijesen si existe alguna manera de poder cambiar el color de un conjunto de días en el control `Calendar` de Windows Forms. Sería para el Framework 2.0

He buscado a ver si existe algún metodo o propiedad que permita poner en color una fecha concreta pero lo más que he visto es que permite poner en Bold, pero no permite nada más. Quizás alguien haya podido hacer esto de alguna manera sencilla.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio urko. Por favor brinda más detalles sobre tu problema, como qué has intentado y qué te detiene. De esa manera, la pregunta podrá ser re abierta.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Buenas ,se trata de la clase por defecto que ofrece Windows Forms para implementar el calendario. He buscado a ver si existe algun metodo o propiedad que permita poner en color una fecha concreta pero lo mas que he visto es que permite poner en Bold , pero no permite nada mas. Quizas alguien haya podido hacer esto de alguna manera sencilla. Un saludo.

Comment: @Urko según esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/199278/4092887). No parece posible modificar el color del control `DateTimePicker`.

Answer (score 2):

Lamentablemente, **esto no es posible**.
El componente de calendar de winforms no permite personalizar el calendario de ninguna forma para poder resaltar los días. La única forma que habría de hacerlo sería creando un componente propio o heredando del mismo e implementando la funcionalidad por ti mismo.

No obstante, esto no es un problema común y ya hay gente que se ha encontrado con ese problema y le ha dado la solución creando un componente nuevo.
Si tuviera que recomendar alguno, diría que [Another Month Calendar](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10840/Another-Month-Calendar) cumpliría con tus necesidades y es un componente reconocido y ampliamente utilizado.

Answer (score 0):

Ulitiza el evento DayRender

```
                void DayRender(Object source, DayRenderEventArgs e) 
              {

                 if (!e.Day.IsOtherMonth && !e.Day.IsWeekend)
                    e.Cell.BackColor=System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;

                 if (e.Day.Date.Day == 18)
                    e.Cell.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;

              }
```

Comment: _DayRender_ es el evento del calendario para ASP.NET; la pregunta está para Winforms.